# facing issues in .htaccess rewrite URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url

I am rewriting my website URL with .htaccess but facing issues, I didnt know about rewrite URL, I just copy and paste the code from internet,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ page.php? [L,QSA]
```

This works for me and redirects, **www.domain.com/page.php?id=1**  to **www.domain.com/page?id=1**.

But the problem is arised when I open **www.domain.com/someotherpage.php** then it redirects me to **page.php**.

And also what ever I write in URL randomly its open **www.domain.com/page** for example

```
domain.com/any
domain.com/thing
domain.com/written
```

I did some researched for this issue but coudn't find any solution, then I asked my question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code for adding `.php` extension:

```
RewriteEngine On

# show 404 for .php requests
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.php[?\s/] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: its is possible that when anyone try domain.com/page.php it will show error 404 and so that no one can see which platform my website is built.

Comment: thanks its working, but shows **PAGE NOT FOUND** instead of **404 ERROR**.

Comment: @Syed What's the difference?  A 404 error _is_ a page not found.  See the answer's status code `[R=404]`.

Comment: 404 Error is a page in sever which can be redesign/edit while its show s **Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.** which cant be editable.

Answer (score 0):

You should just use mod_negotiation and turn on Multiviews:

```
Options Multiviews
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to put the allowed files that can be accessed from the root

```
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|txt|gif|jpg|png|css|swf|JPG|jpeg|html|woff|ttf|svg|htm|cur|PNG|JPEG|GIF|php|whatever_file_type)$ index.php
```

Try the solition it works in zend framework if you want to access php script other than index.php in public/ directory.